# How To find a single value from a cell

Tags: vba, excel

A Cell has range of values separated by commas. How to find a single value from that cell?
The below code is not working

```
Public Sub Search_ChangeInitiator()

    Dim Company As String

      Company = GazelleValidation1.Company2.Value

      Company = Replace(Company, "AZ ", " ")
      Company = Replace(Company, "EXT ", " ")
      Company = Replace(Company, "AZB EXT ", " ")

      Company = Trim(Company)

      Dim sh As Worksheet
      Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validate")
      Dim ans As Range

         Dim InitiatorValue As Range

         Set InitiatorValue = Worksheet("Validate").Range("H2").Select

   Set ans = InitiatorValue.Find(what:=Company, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ans Is Nothing Then
        Gazellevalidation2.Pchnageinitiator.Value = "Not Added"
    Else
        Gazellevalidation2.Pchnageinitiator.Value = "Added"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *the code below is not working* is too broad. Does that means an error raises? Please, edit your question with an output of what you want to get

Comment: Please give (1) some sample input data (2) output data of your actual code and (3) output data that you would expect from your code.

Comment: There are lots of functions in Excel to match/extract substrings. Showing us some sample data and expected output (as per @Pᴇʜ's comment would help determine which to advise on.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is split into items by a deliminator character (in this case commas) then you can use `Split` to turn it into an array:

```
Sub TestingTheSplitFunction()
    Dim ValueArray() As String 'Create an array variable
    ValueArray = Split("A,B,C,D", ",") 'Populate it with the items in your list (here "A", "B", "C" and "D")

    'Everything except the last line is just to make the example more visual
    Dim lReturn As Long, sTest As String
    sTest = "X"

    While Not IsNumeric(sTest)
        sTest = InputBox("Which item in the list would you like to retrieve?", Default:="1")
        If sTest = "" Then Exit Sub 'If you click cancel then stop.
    Wend 'Keep trying until we get a number or Cancel
    lReturn = CLng(sTest) + LBound(ValueArray) - 1 'If the Array starts at 0 then the first item is at position 0

    If lReturn < LBound(ValueArray) Then '0 or negative
        MsgBox "That's not a real position", vbCritical
    ElseIf lReturn > UBound(ValueArray) Then 'Larget than list size
        MsgBox "There are not that many items in the list!", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox ValueArray(lReturn) 'Tells you the value
    End If

    Erase ValueArray 'Free up the Array Memory
End Sub
```